# How to insert new values to Wordpress user Firstname and Surname Fields via DB

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom sign up form in my Wordpress site which has confirmation email functionality for activating the account. For the confirmation step am keeping another DB table where am keeping the pending users info and when they are going with confirmation link then am copying the info from that table and adding to wp_users table. The issue is that i have First Name and Surname fields which info is being kept in another Wp table called wp_usermeta.

So my question is how i can insert the corresponding user firstname, surname when am adding the user to wp_users after confirmation like this

```
$checkUserID = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM pendingwpusers WHERE token = '".$gettokenval."'");
              $checkUserIDMain = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM store_users WHERE TrackNumber = '".$gettokenval."'"); 
              //$aaaa = mysql_num_rows($checkUserIDMain);
             //var_dump($checkUserIDMain);
                if($checkUserID && $checkUserIDMain == 0){    
                    foreach ($checkUserID as $checkUser) {
                        //if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){}else{mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);}
                        $hashedpass = md5($checkUser->user_pass);
                        $wpdb->insert(
                            'store_users',
                            array(
                                'user_login' => $checkUser->user_login,
                                'user_pass' => $hashedpass,
                                'user_nicename' => $checkUser->user_nicename,
                                'user_email' => $checkUser->user_email,
                                'user_registered' => $checkUser->user_registered,
                                'display_name' => $checkUser->display_name,
                                'TrackNumber' => $checkUser->token
                            ),
                            array(
                                    '%s',
                                    '%s',
                                    '%s',
                                    '%s',
                                    '%s',
                                    '%s',
                                    '%s',
                                    '%s'
                            )
                        ); 
                    }
              }
```

$checkUserID variable table is the one where am keeping pending users which yet did not click on activation link

$checkUserIDMain variable table is the wp_users table where i need to add the verified users

Comment: I can' understand what is going wrong ? What is the problem about `wp_usermeta` table ? you mean you are able to get the user_id, but not his name because it is stored in another table ?

Comment: I need to store User First Name and Surname gotted from the form to the corresponding user. How i provided the code above am adding new Wp user by Db so don't know how to add the firstname and surname in this same way for that same user @Random. Any ideas?

Comment: So you mean your actual code is using `$checkUserID` to add a user, and you want to add the data you found in `$checkUserIDMain` ? could you edit your question and add the content of `$checkUserIDMain` ? to see how to use it ? (by uncommenting the `var_dump($checkUserIDMain)` for instance)

Comment: I am adding the data to the $checkUserIDMain table which is wp_users table. Am getting all user info from another table so all i could insert only first name and surnname can't as they are on the wp_usermeta table

Comment: How i can get the added the user ID and then fill prefferred info to that corresponding table info? Any ideas @Random

Comment: That's very hard to understand what you say. Can you please edit your question to add the content of your variables `$checkUserID` and `$checkUserIDMain`, so it will be easier to understand where are stored each data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110911/discussion-between-random-and-anahit-dev).